# Getting typescript error on react-query mutation

Tags: react-query

I am getting cached data by getting the user on SSR... so this is a user, I can get data from thru-out the app. Whenever I try to get at "user properties".... I always get a TS error, like the following:

[image]

I tried, but not working:

```
   export default function useUserCache (select?: $FixMe): QueryObserverResult<User, Error>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `QueryObserverResult` contains a `data` property where all your data, and likely also the email, is.